# Is there a better way to get element value using Appium on Android?

Tags: appium, appium-android

I am writing automation for [Sam's Club Android application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rfi.sams.android&hl=en_US) using [Appium Java Client](https://github.com/appium/java-client).

On Item Details screen, there is a price field. I am trying to get price value. The issue is that there is no text for that element.

[image: Item Details Price]

I looked through page source and searched to see if there is a price value anywhere - but it does not seem to be present anywhere in the page source.

What I ended up doing is taking screenshot of that element and running that small screenshot image through [Tess4j](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/).

```
    // find element
    AndroidElement el = (AndroidElement) driver.findElement(By.id("com.rfi.sams.android:id/item_details_price"));

    // do a screenshot of the element
    File imageFile = el.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

    // use Tessaract to recognize the number from image
    ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();
    instance.setDatapath("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tessdata");
    instance.setTessVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789");
    String ocrResult = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
```

It works great and I can get the value this way, but it feels like I am doing some overkill here. Is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: Did you checked the elements parents `RelativeLayout` and `LinearLayout`? Does anyone of them has text property set?

Comment: @WasiqBhamia Yes, i did check parents and none of them had property set. Developers ended up modifying text parameter to show the price.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can ask your developer team to put **automation id**/**cont-desc** in the price tag,

Or you can inspect the element using **Appium Desktop Inspector** and see if the price tag has specific automation id/cont-desc.

If you have cont-desc in price tag then you can access the price tag as:

```
MobileElement element= driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("automation id here");
System.Out.Println(element.getText());
```

Comment: You did not get the question. I don't have problems locating element. Look at screenshot i included, there is no text for that element, text property is empty.

Comment: you are using uiautomatorviewer. can you inspect the same screen with appium desktop inspector and check if text is visible there? Also you can talk with your developer team about how they are using the price tag there? They may be using some kind of image for the price tag. If possible ask them to place text.

Comment: I have tried appium desktop inspector and there is no text as well. Unfortunately there is no way for me to talk to their developers. Thank you anyways.